# Flutter Tutorial

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am following the tutorial offered in flutter.io
In the fourth part of the tutorial, I'm having trouble understanding the following passage:

```
Widget _buildSuggestions() {
  return ListView.builder(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
  itemBuilder: /*1*/ (context, i) {
    if (i.isOdd) return Divider(); /*2*/

    final index = i ~/ 2; /*3*/
    if (index >= _suggestions.length) {
      _suggestions.addAll(generateWordPairs().take(10)); /*4*/
    }
    return _buildRow(_suggestions[index]);
  });
```

}

Specifically in the following line:

```
final index = i ~/ 2; /*3*/
```

Could someone explain the purpose to me when inserting this line?

[Link](https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/codelab#step-4-create-an-infinite-scrolling-listview) to the tutorial page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `itemBuilder` lambda will be called many times with different values of `i`. When `i` is odd (1, 3, 5, 7, ...) it will return a `Divider`. Which leaves us with the cases when it's even (0, 2, 4, 6, ...). The line `index = i ~/ 2;` means divide `i` by 2 (using integer maths) and assign to `index`, which will now, of course, be 0, 1, 2, 3, etc.

That's used as the index into the `suggestions` `List` (aka array).

It will display alternating rows of suggestions and dividers.

Comment: Hey I am new to flutter. I have checked in some tutorials in ListView.builder they have to pass length as well. But in this they are not passing length, so how they are calculating rows.? If anybody know please explain.

Comment: In this question the list is infinite; if the `ListView` asks for a row that doesn't yet exist, the builder adds more rows, here: `_suggestions.addAll`. If you add `itemCount`, the max `index` passed to the builder is limited by that. See: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html